# Is it feasible using YOLO for pallet detection?

Tags: python, deep-learning, yolo

I'm trying to implement a pallet detector with YOLOv2 but I have serious doubts that it will work because I want also to recognize the objects contained in the palled. I trained it already with different hyperparameters that worked for me with other objects in those images. I would like something like this: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/htu7i.png].

Would it be possible if I have enough data? If not, how could I do it?

Comment: What if you train it on the items in the pallets, then postprocess the result (which would be the bounding boxes of the various items) with non-deep-learning algorithms to find the "hulls" of distinct items, which should be the pallets?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to identify that these are two stacks, and then want to identify that one stack is of the Silver colored Coke and the other one is the Red colored coke, or whatever you have named them?

Comment: I forgot to comment that I already have anorher network to identify the products, maybe I can do something parting from there, but in that case, isn't there too much variability?